# How to pause a form in Visual C# until another form is closed

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my program I will press a button, and it will load form2.  I do not want the program in form1 to continue running until the user closes form2.  Then program execution continues in form1 right after the line that loads form2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you want to show a modalled dialog.

```
public class MyForm1 : Form
{

  public void ShowDialog2()
  {
    MyForm2 form2 = new MyForm2();
    form2.ShowDialog(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

[Form.ShowDialog Method (IWin32Window)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You call the .ShowDialog function on the form you want to show.

.Show simply shows the new form.  Calling .ShowDialog causes the calling form to block until execution returns from the shown form.

The result returned from the call to .ShowDialog will tell you if the user hit 'Okay' or 'No' or cancelled the form by clicking the x in the corner.